# Raspberry Pi wireless internet won't work

Tags: wireless

So, I recently had to reconfigure my wireless network because it wouldn't connect on Raspbian for the life of me, although it could connect on noobs. I reconfigured it and such however whenever I try using the wireless network it says the address of the site has been moved, even if I search a single letter, I really need help.

Comment: "I really need help" try https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here is another help https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/. Try it and tell us what help section do you run into problems and what are the problems exactly.